# Run Emulator on One PC & Run The Code on Another PC

Tags: android, windows, flutter, emulation

am trying to run an android emulator on a windows pc and then am trying to run the code on another windows PC.

Like, i have a window pc with 8gb ram so it can't carry an emulator and still run the code together, so since i have 2 windows pc (not hign end), am trying to make use of both in order to make my work more faster as it always get super slow when i run my code and an emulator on one PC.

Am a flutter dev and that is what am using for coding in android, so if anyone knows of a way please do suggest it here, i will mean a lot to me and to some other people who are running into such problems.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried researching about this but it seems that it is quite easy to do if i had learnt react native instead as i can use expo for this and it will work find, but since am using flutter and since flutter don't have expo like software then am finding it hard to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run an emulator on one computer and run code on another computer, you need to have both computers connected to the same network. Here's how you can do this:

1. Install an emulator on the first computer. For example, if you want to use Android emulator, you can install Android Studio.
2. Start the emulator on the first computer. This will create a virtual device that runs on the first computer.
3. Connect the second computer to the same network as the first computer.
4. On the second computer, use an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) like Android Studio to develop your code.
5. In the IDE, select the virtual device created on the first computer as the target for running your code.
6. Run your code on the second computer, and it will be executed on the virtual device running on the first computer.

**Note: The steps may vary depending on the specific emulator and IDE you're using.**

Comment: Hmmm, do you mean it's this simple, if so then how can the second computer dictate the first computer emulator even if they are connected to the same network, some complicated answer I saw earlier was talking about using a port forwarding tool for this. Can you please explain your approach?

Comment: Would you please provide more detail on step 5?  I’m condiering doing this, but I’m uncertain how to select the virtual device on the remote computer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

PC A is the one with emulator, over Android Studio hedgehog (Windows 10)

PC B is the the one with the Android Studio and the source code

- PC A and PC B must be under the same local network (ex connected to
  the same wifi)
- You need the local network ip address of PC A
- On PC A you need make a search for this tool: trivial_portforward.exe
  is an old exe, so far working for me, but was hard to find.

From PC A:

1. Run your emulator
2. Then on a terminal run a command like this `trivial_portforward.exe 1234 127.0.0.1 5555`
3. Maybe firewall warn appear, whitelist trivial_portfoward

Now on PC B: run the adb command to connect a device like this: `adb connect <PC A ip address>:1234` ex: `adb connect 192.168.0.1:1234`

On your emulator on PC A check for the auth for usb debug and allow access

Now on your Android Studio on PC B you should be able to run your code on the emulator on PC A.

Explanation:

We need to forward LAN port to local 5555 port of emulators. So the 1234 value could be your choice but there will be the port to listen to connections forwarded.